# Jackson: ignore empty object

Tags: java, jackson, spring-restcontroller

If the value of the field `name` in the `inner` class is null, then

> {"id": 123, "inner": {}}

is returned as a response. However, if the value to `inner` is returned as {}, the key-value pair

> "inner": {}

should be ignored entirely, so the response is

> {"id": 123}

. How can this be achieved? I thought it could be achieved with `@JsonInclude(JsonInclude.Include.NON_NULL)` but it did not solve the problem.

```
@RestController
public class ItemController {
    @Autowired
    ItemService itemService;

    @GetMapping("/item")
    public Item getItem() {
        return itemService.getItem(); // {"id": 123,"inner": {}} is returned but should be {"id": 123}
    }
}
```

```
@Service
public class ItemService {
    public Item getItem() {
        Item.Inner inner = new Item.Inner();
        Item item = new Item();
        item.setInner(inner);
        item.setId(123);

        return item;
    }
}
```

```
@Data
public class Item {
    private int id;
    private Inner inner;

    @JsonInclude(JsonInclude.Include.NON_NULL)
    @Data
    public static class Inner {
        private String name;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `@JsonInclude(value = JsonInclude.Include.CUSTOM, valueFilter = Inner .class)` on `Inner` field in `Item` class, but to make this work you need to override hashcode and equals method in `Item` class.

Basically, the `equals` method in Inner class will be called when deciding whether or not inner object should be excluded or not. If equals returns `true`, then the object will be excluded from response.
So make the method match anything you want to filter out and return `false` for anything that should be written out normally.

You can read more details [here](https://cowtowncoder.medium.com/jackson-tips-filtering-with-jsoninclude-27f08979514c)

For your particular case, the following code should work :

```
@Data
public class Item {
    private int id;

    @JsonInclude(value = JsonInclude.Include.CUSTOM, valueFilter = Inner .class)
    private Inner inner;

    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public Inner getInner() {
        return inner;
    }

    public void setInner(Inner inner) {
        this.inner = inner;
    }

    
    @Data
    public static class Inner {
        private String name;

        public String getName() {
            return name;
        }

        public void setName(String name) {
            this.name = name;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean equals(Object o) {
            if (this == o) return true;
            if (o == null || getClass() != o.getClass()) return false;
            Inner inner = (Inner) o;
            return Objects.equals(name, inner.name);
        }

        @Override
        public int hashCode() {
            return Objects.hash(name);
        }
    }
}
```

**NOTE**: `@JsonInclude(JsonInclude.Include.NON_NULL)` will ignore null fields, so if you put it on class level for `Inner` class you will get response like this (it will ignore `name` field in Inner class since it's value is `null`) :

```
{
    "id": 123,
    "inner": {}
}
```

That will also not work if you put it on class level for class `Item` since your `Inner` object is not null, it's empty object, so that will produce this:

```
{
    "id": 123,
    "inner": {
        "name": null
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Please try with below at the class level.

```
@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)
@JsonInclude(JsonInclude.Include.NON_NULL)
```

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

By using `JsonInclude` annotation, it will remove the empty values.

```
@Data
@JsonInclude(JsonInclude.Include.NOT_NULL)
public class Item {
    private int id;
    private Inner inner;

    public static class Inner {
        private String name;
    }
}
```